# Mongodb exists after claiming that there is no disk space while disk was not full

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

We run a Replicaset with 2 Datanodes and an Arbiter.

The Secondary failed at 03:29 on saturday claiming that there is no disk space ==> error 28.
Although there were about 200 GB of space left on the harddrive.

At this point i don't understand why this happend and I am afraid of data loss some day when it happens without notice.

Any idea ?

Extract of the Mongo Log:

```
Sat Aug 10 03:29:22.261 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.8.0.1:52549 #248377 (7 connections now open)
Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.537 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.88, filling with zeroes...
Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.650 [FileAllocator] FileAllocator: posix_fallocate failed: errno:28 No space left on device falling back
Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.659 [FileAllocator] error: failed to allocate new file: /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.88 size: 2146435072 failure creating new datafile; lseek failed for fd 242 with errno: errno:2 No such file or directory.  will try again in 10 seconds
Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.770 [repl writer worker 8] ERROR: writer worker caught exception: Can't take a write lock while out of disk space on: { ts: Timestamp 1376098179000|25, h
Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.770 [repl writer worker 9]   Fatal Assertion 16360
Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.770 [repl writer worker 12] ERROR: writer worker caught exception: Can't take a write lock while out of disk space on: { ts: Timestamp 1376098179000|20, h: -3082101225348979057, v: 2, op: "i", ns: "productive.flags", o: { _id: ObjectId('52059783ddb858150e378c0e'), creation: 1376098179, mid: ObjectId('52059783ddb858150e378c0d'), start: 0, lastchange: 0, flags: { rf: 0, uf: 0, pf: 0, pd: 0, urlf: 0, ue: 0, de: 0, ep: 0, us: 0, ds: 0 }, rawid: ObjectId('52059783ddb858150e378c0d') } }
Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.770 [repl writer worker 12]   Fatal Assertion 16360
0xdd2331 0xd92323 0xc231db 0xd9fe71 0xe1aad9 0x7fce6dcd0e9a 0x7fce6cfe3cbd 
0xdd23310xdd2331 0xd92323  0xd92323 0xc231db0xc231db  0xd9fe710xd9fe71  0xe1aad90xe1aad9  0x7fce6dcd0e9a0x7fce6dcd0e9a  0x7fce6cfe3cbd0x7fce6cfe3cbd  

Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.847 [repl writer worker 5] ERROR: writer worker caught exception: Can't take a write lock while out of disk space on: { ts: Timestamp 1376098179000|102, h: 5265118743163217604, v: 2, op: "i", ns: "rawdata.tw", o: { _id: Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.847 [repl writer worker 5]   Fatal Assertion 16360
Sat Aug 10 03:29:40.847 [repl writer worker 2]   Fatal Assertion 16360
0xdd2331 0xd92323 0xc231db 0xd9fe71 0xe1aad9 0x7fce6dcd0e9a 0x7fce6cfe3cbd 0xdd2331 0xd92323 
0xc231db 0xd9fe71 0xe1aad9 0x7fce6dcd0e9a 0x7fce6cfe3cbd 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdd2331]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xa3) [0xd92323]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x13b) [0xc231db]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x281) [0xd9fe71]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xe1aad9]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7fce6dcd0e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fce6cfe3cbd]
Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.138 [repl writer worker 5] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.138 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdd2331]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xa3) [0xd92323]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x13b) [0xc231db]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x281) [0xd9fe71]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xe1aad9]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7fce6dcd0e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fce6cfe3cbd]
Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.139 [repl writer worker 2] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.139 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdd2331]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xa3) [0xd92323]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x13b) [0xc231db]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x281) [0xd9fe71]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xe1aad9]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7fce6dcd0e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fce6cfe3cbd]
Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.139 [repl writer worker 12] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.139 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdd2331]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xa3) [0xd92323]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x13b) [0xc231db]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x281) [0xd9fe71]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xe1aad9]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7fce6dcd0e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fce6cfe3cbd]
Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.139 [repl writer worker 9] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.139 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdd2331]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xa3) [0xd92323]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x13b) [0xc231db]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x281) [0xd9fe71]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xe1aad9]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7fce6dcd0e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fce6cfe3cbd]
Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.140 [repl writer worker 8] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.140 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).


Sat Aug 10 03:29:41.240 Backtrace:
0xdd2331 0x6cfb19 0x7fce6cf264a0 0x7fce6cf26425 0x7fce6cf29b8b 0xd9235e 0xc231db 0xd9fe71 0xe1aad9 0x7fce6dcd0e9a 0x7fce6cfe3cbd 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdd2331]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x399) [0x6cfb19]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0) [0x7fce6cf264a0]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x7fce6cf26425]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x17b) [0x7fce6cf29b8b]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xde) [0xd9235e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x13b) [0xc231db]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x281) [0xd9fe71]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xe1aad9]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7fce6dcd0e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fce6cfe3cbd]
```

Comment: Maybe better asked on dba.stackexchange.com or maybe serverfault.com as I don't see a programming question for StackOverflow.

Comment: maybe... on mongodb.org they advise to post it here http://www.mongodb.org/forums

Comment: That's for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a bug in MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3759). As of today it remains unresolved.

The best advice I can give you is to ensure you have plenty of available disk space at all times.